# MongoDB Compound text search

Tags: mongodb, full-text-search, full-text-indexing

I have a collection like this in my mongo database, let's say it's called taxonomic.

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5810e15a762a39b41912a131"),
  "validName" : "Eros",
  "idUser" : ObjectId("1")
}
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5810e15a762a39b41912a132"),
 "validName" : "Eros",
 "idUser" : ObjectId("2")
}
```

I've already created a compound index to be able to search for the two values I want, such as this.

```
db.taxonomic.createIndex({"idUser":1,"validName":1})
```

Now, I want to be able to search and get a return from it only when both of the parameters are found on the same document of the collections, here's my try:

```
db.taxonomic.find({$text:{$search:"Eros 2"}},{idUser:1,validName:1})
```

The problem with this method is that it will return any match of "Eros" OR "2", what I want is a return of the values when "Eros" AND "2" are matched in a document of the collection.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: You need to add a text index ,Can you tell me on which field you created text index??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think you require a text Index for it if you only want specific string

```
db.taxonomic.find({"$or" : [{"validName" : "Eros"},{"validName" : "2"}]},{idUser:1,validName:1})
```

Comment: I was looking for an 'and' operator, but it still answered my question. Thanks.